# Finding the locations of specific coordinates from an array of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of coordinates as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
values_to_test = np.array([[1 , 0],[2 , 0],[2 , 0.5],[1 , 0.5],[0 , 0],[2 , 1], [0 , 0.5],[1 , 1],[0 , 1]])
```

As my ultimate goal, I need to choose the positions from the `values_to_test`  that contain the specific coordinates of the following array:

`specific_values=np.array([[1,0],[0,0],[1,1]])`

Hence, I'm expecting a result like: `[True,False,False,False,True,False,False,True,False]`

I know if this was a `1D` array I could use `np.where` but I cannot think about a way to handle this problem.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of [`numpy.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) and [`numpy.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html#numpy.any) like so:

```py
>>> (values_to_test[:, None] == specific_values).all(axis=-1).any(axis=-1)
array([ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: Glad was of some help! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
values_to_test = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0.5], [1, 0.5], [
                          0, 0], [2, 1], [0, 0.5], [1, 1], [0, 1]])
specific_values = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]])

_1_j = np.array([[1], [1j]])

print([x in specific_values@_1_j for x in values_to_test@_1_j])
>>>[True, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a combination of using `np.where`, `np.prod` and list comprehension:

```py
values_to_test = np.array([[1 , 0],[2 , 0],[2 , 0.5],
                           [1 , 0.5],[0 , 0],[2 , 1], 
                           [0 , 0.5],[1 , 1],[0 , 1]])
specific_values=np.array([[1,0],[0,0],[1,1]])

output = [np.where(np.prod(values_to_test == x, axis = -1)) for x in specific_values]
```

Output:

```
[(array([0], dtype=int64),),
 (array([4], dtype=int64),),
 (array([7], dtype=int64),)]
```

You can clean it up too with:

```py
output = [np.where(np.prod(values_to_test == x, axis = -1))[0][0] for x in specific_values]

[0, 4, 7] #output
```